# ERROR: attempt to delete row 0 from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update (Swift and Realm)

Tags: swift, realm, tableview

So I'm fairly new to Realm and Swift and I'm currently building my first Gym App and I'm currently struggling with this error. I get this error each time I attempt to swipe to delete a row/section.

I think that I'm updating my Realm correctly, but apparently not because I keep getting the same error.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import SwipeCellKit


class WorkoutsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {


    let realm = try! Realm()

    var workouts : Results<Workouts>?
    var days : Results<WeekDays>!

    var daysOfWeek : [String] = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednsday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

    let picker = UIPickerView()


    @IBOutlet weak var WorkoutsTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        WorkoutsTableView.delegate = self
        WorkoutsTableView.dataSource = self

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self

        loadCategories()

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        tableView.rowHeight = 80.0

        //Populate based on the # of workouts in each day.

        let day = days[section]
        return day.workouts.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return days[section].day
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return days.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SwipeTableViewCell

        cell.delegate = self

        if (days?[indexPath.row]) != nil {
            cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
            //Populate with titles of workouts based on section/day of the week.
            //cell.textLabel?.text = days?[indexPath.row].workouts[indexPath.row].name
            cell.textLabel?.text = days[indexPath.section].workouts[indexPath.row].name
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {

        guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

        let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in

            if let workoutForDeletion = self.days?[indexPath.row] {
                do {
                    try self.realm.write {
                        self.realm.delete(workoutForDeletion)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error deleting workout, \(error)")
                }
            }
            self.WorkoutsTableView.reloadData()
        }
        // customize the action appearance
        deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete-icon")

        return [deleteAction]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsOptionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> SwipeOptions {
        var options = SwipeOptions()
        options.expansionStyle = .destructive
        return options
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }



    @IBAction func AddWorkoutButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var textField = UITextField()

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Workout", message: "Please name your workout...", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Workout", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
                //Add workout to database
                //Create a two dimensional array object in Realm with numbers corresponding to each day of the week.
                //Append workouts to the day in the dictionary that the user selects.
            let newWorkout = Workouts()
            let dow = WeekDays()

            dow.day = self.daysOfWeek[self.picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
            newWorkout.name = textField.text!
            dow.workouts.append(newWorkout)

            self.save(newDay: dow)
        }

        alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "Muscle Group"
            textField = alertTextField
            alertTextField.inputView = self.picker
        }

        alert.addAction(addAction)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func save(newDay: WeekDays){
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(newDay)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error saving workout \(error)")
        }
        WorkoutsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func loadCategories(){
        days = realm.objects(WeekDays.self)
        WorkoutsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func EditWorkout(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    }

}

extension WorkoutsViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return daysOfWeek[row]
    }
}




class WeekDays : Object {
    @objc dynamic var day : String = ""
    let workouts = List<Workouts>()
}

class Workouts : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    var parentDay = LinkingObjects(fromType: WeekDays.self, property: "workouts")
}
```

Comment: What does the error say? And where does it occur? What efforts have you made to solve the problem?

Comment: The error is in the title. It happens when I try to swipe/delete a cell, I mentioned that already. I tried reloading the data of view controller after the cell is deleted, and although the cell and data do get deleted, the app still crashes with the error "attempt to delete row 0 from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update"

Comment: What ios / Xcode version are you using?

Comment: 11.2.1 is the version of Xcode

Comment: Never mind, I think I just forgot to subclass the SwipeTableViewController. Which kind of begs the question, how can I subclass SwipeTableViewController if I'm already subclassing a UIViewController? I know that multiple inheritance is not allowed. So how can I go about inheriting from the cocoapod? Thank!

Comment: Is this code `if let workoutForDeletion = self.days?[indexPath.row]` intended to delete a day plus all of the child workouts listed in that section? I ask because it's being populated like this `cell.textLabel?.text = days[indexPath.section].`. Does *never mind* mean that you corrected the issue but subclassing SwipeTableViewController or are you having another issue - there are a couple of other similar questions which is why I ask.

Comment: @Jay I actually didn't correct it.I'm still having trouble with this. Yes, I'm trying to delete the day and all the child workouts for that section, but it keeps crashing on me. Do I have to subclass SwipeTableViewController? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what `SwipeTableViewController` is and it doesn't appear in your question. You're handling your tableView delegate methods within the `WorkoutsViewController` which is pretty common. Your error is a bit unclear as you're populating your table from this call `days[indexPath.section].workouts[indexPath.row]` but then when something is swiped to delete, you're deleting `self.days?[indexPath.row]` - it's difficult to understand what exactly you're trying to delete and along with that, what action is being taken - is the user swiping on a section? A row? Something else?

Comment: @Jay The user is swiping on a row but I'm basically trying to delete both the section and the row within that section, but how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the dereferencing of `self.days`. It *looks like* this is an array of days, each containing an array of workouts. This is supported by the `cellForRowAt` function operation for working out what is in each row:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = days[indexPath.section].workouts[indexPath.row].name
```

But for your deletion code you are dereferencing `days` only by the row number, i.e.:

```
 if let workoutForDeletion = self.days?[indexPath.row] {
```

There is no use of `indexPath.section` there. Correcting that will help.

You may want to look into the usual code for deleting rows though, which is to use code similar to below:-

```
days[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row) // Make this a realm update though
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

Which saves the complete reload of data and gives you a nicer UI update.