# How to delete a section and a row from a TableView with Realm and Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, tableview

ableView. I'm currently working on this gym app and I'm hoping to get a little bit of guidance here.

Basically what I want is to be able to swipe the cell and delete the row and the section associated with that row.

When I run my code, this is the error I get

**'attempt to delete row 0 from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update'**

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
class WorkoutsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, SwipeTableViewCellDelegate, CollapsibleTableSectionDelegate {


    let realm = try! Realm()

    var workouts : Results<Workouts>?
    var days : Results<WeekDays>!

    var daysOfWeek : [String] = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednsday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

    let picker = UIPickerView()


    @IBOutlet weak var WorkoutsTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        WorkoutsTableView.delegate = self
        WorkoutsTableView.dataSource = self


        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self

        loadCategories()

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        tableView.rowHeight = 80.0

        //Populate based on the # of workouts in each day.

        let day = days[section]
        return day.workouts.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return days[section].day
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return days.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SwipeTableViewCell

        cell.delegate = self

        if (days?[indexPath.section]) != nil {
            cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
            //Populate with titles of workouts based on section/day of the week.
            //cell.textLabel?.text = days?[indexPath.row].workouts[indexPath.row].name
            cell.textLabel?.text = days[indexPath.section].workouts[indexPath.row].name
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {

        guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

        let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in

            self.updateModel(at: indexPath)

        }
        // customize the action appearance
        deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete-icon")

        return [deleteAction]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsOptionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> SwipeOptions {
        var options = SwipeOptions()
        options.expansionStyle = .destructive
        return options
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }



    @IBAction func AddWorkoutButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var textField = UITextField()
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Workout", message: "Please name your workout...", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Workout", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
                //Add workout to database
                //Create a two dimensional array object in Realm with numbers corresponding to each day of the week.
                //Append workouts to the day in the dictionary that the user selects.
            let newWorkout = Workouts()
            let dow = WeekDays()
            dow.day = self.daysOfWeek[self.picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
            newWorkout.name = textField.text!
            dow.workouts.append(newWorkout)

            self.save(newDay: dow)
        }

        alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "Muscle Group"
            textField = alertTextField
            alertTextField.inputView = self.picker
        }

        alert.addAction(addAction)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func save(newDay: WeekDays){
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(newDay)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error saving workout \(error)")
        }
        WorkoutsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func updateModel(at indexPath: IndexPath){
        if let workoutForDeletion = self.days?[indexPath.section]{
            do {
                try self.realm.write {
                    self.realm.delete(workoutForDeletion)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error deleting workout, \(error)")
            }
        }
        self.WorkoutsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func loadCategories(){
        days = realm.objects(WeekDays.self)
        WorkoutsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func EditWorkout(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    }

}

extension WorkoutsViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return daysOfWeek[row]
    }
}



class WeekDays : Object {
    @objc dynamic var day : String = ""
    let workouts = List<Workouts>()
}

class Workouts : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    var parentDay = LinkingObjects(fromType: WeekDays.self, property: "workouts")
}
```

Comment: In the `cellForRowAt` data source method, you never specify which cells go in which sections. Therefore, your table is one large section, which is why you can't delete the second section (it doesn't exist).

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as the question you asked a couple of days ago (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59128082/error-attempt-to-delete-row-0-from-section-1-but-there-are-only-1-sections-bef/59131062#59131062). You don't seem to have made many/any of the changes suggested in the answer there. Revisit that, look at `tableView.beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.

Comment: Does your code compile at all? days is not an optional and yet you have this: `if let workoutForDeletion = self.days?[indexPath.section]{`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: attempt to delete row 0 from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update (Swift and Realm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59128082/error-attempt-to-delete-row-0-from-section-1-but-there-are-only-1-sections-bef)

Comment: Marked as a duplicate because it's pretty much the same question with the same issue. It's best practice here to stick with one question and update it as more information is asked for. Please review the comments to that question and note you accepted that answer which suggests the issue was resolved. If it didn't help resolve the issue then it should not be accepted. That being said, both that answer and the answer here from @rs7 are very good as the root issue still remains.

Comment: Question -- probably unrelated to the problem: why do you have `cell.delegate = self` inside cellForRowAt

Comment: Is that wrong? Where should I be setting it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to delete a whole section, then your code is correct. Try calling loadCategories instead of reloading your tableView to see if that helps. See updated code below:

Change that line to this instead:

```
func updateModel(at indexPath: IndexPath){
        if let workoutForDeletion = self.days?[indexPath.section] {
            do {
                try self.realm.write {
                    self.realm.delete(workoutForDeletion)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error deleting workout, \(error)")
            }
        }
        self.loadCategories()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so this actually deletes the cell, but how would I go about deleting the section associated with that cell also?

Comment: Oh, you were trying to delete the section? I updated my answer with what I think is the correct code then.

Comment: This is what I get when I try to do implement that 'attempt to delete row 0 from section 2, but there are only 2 sections before the update'

Comment: I don't think you are calling loadCategories though? You are just reloading the table right?

Comment: This is my loadCategories...



func loadCategories(){
        days = realm.objects(WeekDays.self)
        WorkoutsTableView.reloadData()
    }

Comment: This is what I'd do to debug this: Add print statements in your numberOfRows and numberOfSections methods to display the number of rows/sections you are returning and then count how many rows/sections are displayed on your table. See if that's what you are expecting. I can't see anything obvious in your code.